# CMS or other web-tool with deep SQL/Database features for storing large amounts of tabular data

Tags: database, cms, information-management

For examples of types of software that resembles a solution, look towards the bottom of this page.

I'm looking for a self-hosted CMS/CMF/SQL Interface or other web-tool with a WUI/GUI that provides the user with the following **fundamental features** (that must require **very little coding** if any to get working.. some configuration is fine/to be expected):

- The ability to create at least 100 tables.
- With at least 30 columns each.
- That can contain at least 1000 rows per table.
- The data must be retrievable, preferably to be output in something like a HTML table.
- The option of putting tables into a hierarchy (of text identifiers and parent-child-relations) so that it's possible to identify individual - and navigate through large amounts of tables.
- The option for relations **with multiple values for match-comparison (point 1)** to be made between any column to any other column (using at least 3 points: 1. FROM [Trigger Column & Primary value(s) used in match] 2. TO [Seconary value to be matched with], 3. WITH [Tertiary value to replace any value from the 1st point/column or/and will be the value used as a final result/output])

Final notes:

1. The most promising software I've found are: **MyTaskHelper** (Looks promising, but is not self-hosted (which is a big problem in itself) and costs $29/month which quickly adds up to more than what Commercial software costs in a few years), **Processwire** (too much coding required and the system broke down on me upon installing the (officially supported) necessary plugins).
2. I'm constantly trying new software. Currently I'm looking into WAFs... But it doesn't seem like what I'm looking for. And constantly having to look into and trying to learn new types of software is taking its toll.. Hence why I'm reaching out here.
3. I asked almost the same question as this one a couple of months ago, but I think I was far less specific and concise back then, so hopefully this refined version might be clearer and work better. Either way this is likely my last and final question on this topic.

Comment: Did you duplicate much of your question by mistake?

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, I did. Thanks for the notice.